# NodeFactory does not exist in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

The backend of Magento 2 is working fine but when trying to access the frontend it is showing errors. I put magento2 in Developer mode to check the error logs and getting the below errors :

**1. Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class 
      Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\NodeFactory does not exist**

**2. Exception #2 (ReflectionException): Class 
      Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\NodeFactory does not exist**

Tried using the **"php bin/magento setup:di:compile"**, flushed the cache but no helping.

Please help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Exception 0? 
I got the same error. in my case, it is a module class showing in Exception0 reference

```
vendor/magento/module-versions-cms
```

Can you check if this module exist? It is actually a Magento2 Enterprise module.